# Is there a recommended party size for Waterdeep: Dragon Heist?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, waterdeep-dragon-heist, group-scaling

I'm planning on starting a campaign of *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* tomorrow, but it's looking like we may only have two players (plus me as DM) for it. The other published adventures I've used (*Lost Mine of Phandelver* and *Storm King's Thunder*) each say a recommended party size for them, which we haven't always had but helped me figure out how much I needed to adjust the included encounters when we had fewer players. But I can't find within *Dragon Heist* the party size that it's designed for. Due to it being more of an intrigue-based campaign than a hack-and-slash style, does it work just as well if you have two PCs or six?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While not stated explicitly, the norm still appears to be 5 players. However there are useful suggestions on the internet for balancing the module for different numbers of players. One such example is by a [reddit poster who seems to have prepared explicit adjustments for various encounters](https://www.reddit.com/r/WaterdeepDragonHeist/comments/9ldz7k/scaling_for_waterdeep_dragon_heist/).

With two players, you can also consider letting each player run a second character or a [sidekick](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_Sidekicks.pdf).

Comment: DDAL08 seems to be approximately the same - 5 players is considered Average, whereas 6+ is considered Strong and 3-4 is considered Weak.